# Finding area of region using parabolic coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

I am looking to find the area enclosed by the following curves:
$$(x+ \sqrt{x^2+y^2})^\frac{1}{2}=1,\;y=0, \; (*)\;x=\frac{1}{2}(y^\frac{2}{3}-y^\frac{4}{3})$$
in the quadrant $x,y\geq0$ using parabolic coordinates,
$$x=\frac{u^2-v^2}{2},\;y=uv.$$

I know that the first curve reduces to $u=1$, the second gives $uv=0$, but I can't find how to incorporate $(*)$ to then find the integration limits. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: $(*)$ becomes $|v|=u^2$

Comment: @MatthewPilling How did you get to that?

Comment: The relation $x=\frac{1}{2}(y^{2/3}-y^{4/3})$ becomes $$\frac{1}{2}(u^2-v^2)=\frac{1}{2}\Big((uv)^{2/3}-(uv)^{4/3}\Big)$$ which you can write as $$u^2-u^{2/3}v^{2/3}+u^{4/3}v^{4/3}-v^2=0$$ Factor out $u^{2/3}$ from the first two terms and $v^{4/3}$ from the last two terms: $$u^{2/3}(u^{4/3}-v^{2/3})+v^{4/3}(u^{4/3}-v^{2/3})=0$$ By grouping this becomes $$(u^{2/3}+v^{4/3})(u^{4/3}-v^{4/3})=0$$ Hence $$u^{4/3}-v^{2/3}=0\iff u^4=v^2 \iff v=|u|^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express your region as $$\frac{1}{2}(y^{2/3}-y^{4/3})<x<\frac{1-y^2}{2}$$$$0<y<1$$ After applying $x=\frac{1}{2}(u^2-v^2),y=uv$ and doing a bunch of algebra this becomes $$0<v<u^2$$ $$0<u<1$$ Therefore $$\int_0^1 \int_{\frac{1}{2}(y^{2/3}-y^{4/3})}^{\frac{1-y^2}{2}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^1 \int_0^{u^2}\Bigg|\frac{\partial\Big(\frac{1}{2}(u^2-v^2),uv\Big)}{\partial(u,v)}\Bigg|\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}u=\int_0^1 \int _0^{u^2}(u^2+v^2)\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}u$$ The last integral evaluates to $\frac{26}{105}$.

Comment: Thank you for this, there's one thing I'm struggling to see though which is exactly why $u,v\gt 0$?

Comment: Your parabolic transformation $(u,v)\longrightarrow \Big(\frac{u^2-v^2}{2},uv\Big)$ maps $\mathcal{R}=\{(u,v):0<v<u,u>0\}$ into the first quadrant (this is easily verified). Since the region defined by $0<v<u^2,0<u<1$ is contained in $\mathcal{R}$, its image under the parabolic transformation must be contained in the first quadrant.

Comment: Are you familiar with complex analysis? In complex form, the transformation $$(u,v)\longrightarrow \Big(\frac{u^2-v^2}{2},uv\Big)$$ looks like $$z\longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}z^2$$ where $z=u+iv$. Its "inverse" $$z \longrightarrow \sqrt{2z}$$ maps the first quadrant into itself, which is why $x>0,y>0$ implies $u>0,v>0$.

Comment: I haven't covered complex analysis yet. This question prefaces with the transformation given as $$(x,y)\longrightarrow ((x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^\frac{1}{2},(-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^\frac{1}{2}).$$ so I don't know if that makes this easier, transforming in the opposite direction?

Comment: Its because I've noticed that $x,y\geq 0$ can still be satisfied  in the 3$^{rd}$ quadrant in $(u,v)$

Comment: Gotcha. Notice that the range of the transformation you just wrote (which maps the $xy-$ plane to the $uv-$ plane) is contained in the first quadrant since each component is the square root of a number.

Comment: You don't have to consider the third quadrant of the $(u,v)$ plane because, based off of what you just wrote, $(u,v)$ will always be in the first quadrant. It is assumed that $(u,v)$ is the output of some point $(x,y)$ in the transformation you just wrote, so neither component of $(u,v)$ can be negative.

Comment: Sigh, my mistake for overthinking it. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: No problem, and never forget, it is through ones' mistakes that mathematics is truly learned. Embrace your struggle. Easier said than done, I know, but what I say is true.